# How to only use parts of images for LWJGL

Tags: java, image, load, textures, lwjgl

Hey I would like to know if there is a way to only take part of an image and turn it into a texture for LWJGL. Here is my basic code for loading an image and using as a texture. The PNG decoder is from the twl library. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
int floorTexture = glGenTextures();
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream("res/floor.png");
                PNGdecoder decoder = new PNGdecoder(in);
                ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
                decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4, Format.RGBA);
                buffer.flip();
                in.close();
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Failed to find the texture files.");
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Failed to load the texture files.");
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the PNG to a BufferedImage, then use getRGB() to extract the data for the region you are interested in. You may need some additional code to convert the (A)RGB ints to a byte buffer format accepted by GL. For a more detailed example of doing this look at the answer to this question [`LWJGL Textures and Strings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801016/lwjgl-textures-and-strings).

However, instead of this, in GL you typically use texture coordinates to select the right subimage for what you are rendering.

The advantage of this method is that you can use a single [`glDrawElements`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml)/[`glDrawArrays`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) call to render polygons with different textures, improving rendering performance.