# Calling glTexImage2D clears data buffer

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL for its OpenGL bindings and I'm trying to draw a quad with a texture. I have done so successfully, but there is a strange side-effect and I'm unsure why it's presenting itself.

The following code executes when first loading the texture (before the first render). I save the value of `textureID` for when I bind the texture/draw the quad. The following set-up code is taken from an SO answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801016/lwjgl-textures-and-strings).

```
int textureID = GL11.glGenTextures(); // Generate texture ID

GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); // Bind texture ID

// Setup wrap mode
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_CLAMP);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_CLAMP);

// Setup texture scaling filtering
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);

// Send texel data to OpenGL
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

In the rendering loop, I draw the quad with the following code:

```
int texture = TextureLoader.loadTexture(TextureLoader.loadImage("/pc_run/run3.png"));

GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
{
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-hw, -hh);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(+hw, -hh);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(+hw, +hh);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-hw, +hh);
}
GL11.glEnd();
```

So far, this works (and is also wrapped between `glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()` calls). However, whatever I have drawn to the GLContext so far is not displayed. Removing the call to  `GL11.glTexImage2D` in the initialization code, the sprite is not displayed, but everything else (non-textured) is displayed correctly.

Comment: Why are you loading the texture anew for each frame? This will eat up your memory in no time. textures are not garbage collected. Make the generated texture ID a class member variable and load the texture only once!

Comment: I'm only creating the texture when I initialize GL.

Comment: I was just asking, because you have the the call of  TextureLoader.loadTexture in the code you described as rendering code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable texturing (`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) for objects that are not supposed to be textured.

Comment: Thank you. If that is documented somewhere I've really missed big time.