# LWJGL - loading sounds and fonts without slick

Tags: java, fonts, lwjgl, audio

I'm writing Minecraft-like game. For loading Textures and fonts(currently there is no sound) I use slick. Slick is no longer developed and maven repository is unavaible. Is there any other library (except LibGDX) library that can be used to load sounds and fonts for lwjgl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAL is used in many programs and instructions for using it with lwjgl can be found
http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=OpenAL_Tutorial_1_-_Single_Static_Source

Since you said you are doing a minecraft like game I would have assumed the first option you would look at would be the one minecraft itself uses which is PaulsCode sound library located at
http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.0

Answer (score 1):

Seronis answered for sound, but as for fonts, check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872080/1203881) which explains how to render and load textures and fonts easily and quickly.

Comment: I solved this problem - I created 256x256 image with 256 ASCII glypgh and used TWL PNGLoader to load the image.Then created array of 256 display lists and created drawString() method to draw the string.